# Change caption placement after line break

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb] \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts]{\small Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.60\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor]{\small CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like for the second/third/etc. line of the caption text of the left image to start right under the letter F of the label "Figure 0.1", but not for the image on the right. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,format=plain]{caption}`.

Comment: This changes the caption placement globally. I want it changed only locally, i.e. only for the image on the left, not for the one on the right or any other image in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the caption specific to any figure by adding appropriate `\captionsetup` options before using `\caption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \captionsetup{format=plain}
  \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts.}
  \end{minipage} \hfill
  \captionsetup{format=hang}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.60\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor.}
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put the `\captionsetup{format=plain}` into the minipage there is no need for the following `\captionsetup{format=hang}` anymore.

Answer (score 3):

With KOMA-Script you can use `\setcapindent{1em}` to order an indent of 1 em for the second and following heading lines of tables or figures.  In your case use `0em`.

KOMA-Script has an own mechanismn for captions, if you call package `caption` some of that functionality can not work.

To have bold caption label use with KOMA-Script for example `\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}` to get bold (`\bfseries`) sans serif (`\sffamily`) label. In your given example you didn't change the font for the label. Leave `\sffamily` out if you do not want it.

MWE (see `<=======` for my changes):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting

%\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\setcapindent{0em}%<====================================================
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}% <=======================

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb] \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts]{\small Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.60\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor]{\small CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With a little change of the first MWE you can indent the first figur with 0 em, the second hangs as usual.

changed MWE (see `<==============` for changes):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting

%\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\setcapindent{0em}%<====================================================
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}% <=======================

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb] \centering
{\setcapindent{0em}% <====================================================
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts]{\small Schematic sketch of the p-i-n sample structure for two opposing contacts.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_schematic.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
} \hfill% <====================================================
\begin{minipage}{0.60\textwidth} \centering \resizebox{1.00\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Figures/p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}}
\vspace{-6mm}
\captionof{figure}[CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor]{\small CCD image of the p-i-n sample as seen on the CRT monitor.}
\label{p-i-n_structure_CCD(edited).png}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: This changes the caption placement globally. I want it changed only locally, i.e. only for the image on the left, not for the one on the right or any other image in the document.

Comment: Works fine now.